# loop for changing file endings

Tags: r, loops, csv

I had to split a gigantic csv file up, and now I'd like to process each of them, then stack.

The split up data files are named data-000.csv, data-001.csv, etc., up through 374.

However, I don't know how to get R to read the [i].

```
for (i in 3:3) {
  dat = read.csv("F:data-00[i].csv")
}

**cannot open file 'F:data-[i].csv': No such file or directory**
```

where `dat = read.csv('F:data-003.csv')` works just fine.

How do I replace the suffix and process through my text files?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` to get the value stored in `i` instead of literally using it.  For storing more than one datasets, it would be better to create a NULL `list` and then assign the data into that object

```
lst1 <- vector('list', 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
      lst1[[i]] = read.csv(paste0("F:data-00", i, ".csv")
     }
```

Also, if the digits should be 3 digit with prefix 0s, then  an option is to format with `sprintf`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', 374)
files <- sprintf('F:data-%03d', 1:374)
names(lst1) <- files
for(file in files)  {
    lst1[[file]] <- read.csv(file)
 }
```

---

It can also be easier if we use `lapply` as `paste/sprintf` are vectorized, it can be taken out of the loop

```
lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `map` (from `purrr`) and `read_csv` (from `readr`)

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)    
lst1 <- map(files, read_csv)
```

---

Or using `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- lapply(file, fread)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the multiple routes to the solution. It really helps newbies like me to see a few different ways to do it :)

Comment: Done! And thank you for the knowledge and the nudge :)